# Appended button not calling function when clicked

Tags: javascript

I made a `userscript` that appends two input elements in a `form`, the first working as `textarea` and the second working as `button`. They work perfectly fine on a local/static page but if I try to click on the `button` that should call the `function uuid()`, nothing happens.

Edit: Something I forgot to mention is that this userscript should work together with another userscript that adds/edits elements so maybe there is an issue with loading timings. I thought I had solved the issue making the my custom userscript load when the page finishes to load but I still have issues..

This is the script:

```
var qrform, rbutton, milliseconds, randomnumber, css;
css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
/*jshint multistr: true */
css.innerHTML = "#rb{\
    display: -webkit-flex;\
    display: flex;\
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;\
    align-items: stretch;\
    height: 25px;\
    margin-top: 1px;\
    text-transform: uppercase;\
    font-size: 10px;\
    }\
    #rb #uform + input {\
    text-transform: uppercase;\
    font-size: 10px !important;\
    }\
    #uform{\
    width:95%;\
    text-align:center;\
    }\
    ";
document.body.appendChild(css);
qrform = document.getElementById("qr").getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
rbutton = document.createElement('div');
rbutton.setAttribute("id", "rb");
qrform.appendChild(rbutton);
rbutton.innerHTML = "<input id=\"uform\" type=\"text\" name=\"UUID\" placeholder=\"UUID\" readonly><input type=\"button\" value=\"GENERATE\" onclick=\"uuid()\">";

function uuid() {
    milliseconds = Date.now();
    randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 365 * 86400000);
    document.getElementById("uform").value = milliseconds - randomnumber;
    document.getElementById("uform").readOnly=true;
}
```

---

Edited with the working script:

```
var qrform, rcontainer, rbutton, parentrbutton, milliseconds, randomnumber, css;
css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
/*jshint multistr: true */
css.innerHTML = "#rb{\
    display: -webkit-flex;\
    display: flex;\
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;\
    align-items: stretch;\
    height: 25px;\
    margin-top: 1px;\
    text-transform: uppercase;\
    font-size: 10px;\
    }\
    #rb #uform + input {\
    text-transform: uppercase;\
    font-size: 10px !important;\
    }\
    #uform{\
    width:95%;\
    text-align:center;\
    }\
    ";
document.body.appendChild(css);
qrform = document.getElementById("qr").getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
rcontainer = document.createElement('div');
rcontainer.setAttribute("id", "rb");
qrform.appendChild(rcontainer);
rcontainer.innerHTML = "<input id=\"uform\" type=\"text\" name=\"UUID\" placeholder=\"UUID\" readonly>";
rbutton = document.createElement('input');
rcontainer.appendChild(rbutton);
rbutton.setAttribute("type", "button");
rbutton.setAttribute("value", "generate");
rbutton.addEventListener('click', uuid);

function uuid() {
    milliseconds = Date.now();
    randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 365 * 86400000);
    document.getElementById("uform").value = milliseconds - randomnumber;
    document.getElementById("uform").readOnly=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What errors do you get when you click the button?
You might try defining the function before inserting the button. However, it's generally considered bad practice to use inline onclick like that. It's better to add an event handler.

```
var button = document.createElement('button')
button.addEventListener('click', uuid)
```

Comment: I'll try following your suggestion removing the inline event and doing everything inside my userscript. as you can see the function is correctly called on click but still nothing happens.. https://i.imgur.com/Qv7h1AY.png

Comment: Ah! Somehow moving the onclick event from inline inside the script solved the issue. It's working now! Maybe my userscript manager (tampermonkey) was preventing me from using a bad practice method like that?